# JQM multi-page and php require

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

I have a php-script controlling some JQM-pages. The JQM pages are activated using php require. It works fine for all single-page JQM pages and almost for the multi-page JQM page. The only problem is that the link (anchor) button on the multi-page seems to be dead (href="#page2" for example).

The dead link button works if I reload the multi-page or if I start the multi-page by hand in the browser.

Do you have a solution to this problem (except adding a reload or turning the multi-page into single pages)?

This does not work (all files on server):

index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$action = isset( $_GET['action'] ) ? $_GET['action'] : "";
if ( !$action ) $action = isset( $_POST['action'] ) ? $_POST['action'] : "";
if ($action == 'multi')
   require('multi.php');
else
   require('single.php');
?>
```

single.php:

```
    <?php ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>SINGLE</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/app-icon.png">

</head>
<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="single">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
            <h2>SINGLE 1(1)</h2>    
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <p>This is page single.</p>
            <form action="index.php" method="post" >
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                     <input type="submit" name="action" id="multi" value="multi">
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

multi.php:

```
    <?php ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>MULTI</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/app-icon.png">

</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
            <h2>MULTI 1(2)</h2> 
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <p>This is page 1.</p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a" data-id="nav">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="ui-btn" data-transition="slide" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos= "top" href="#page2">Next</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="page2">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
            <h2>MULTI 2(2)</h2> 
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <p>This is page 2.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Start index.php in the browser, tap multi button, and now the next button is not working...

Comment: Do you have any code? What did you try to solve the problem?

Comment: There is a lot of code so I have to take away a lot to have anything to show. I tried to change the button to run JQM API "change" but with the same result (as expected I guess). I think the general question should be: Can JQM really handle this (require, multi-page, href="#page1") or do I have to go for single pages?

Comment: Your current project might have lots of code, but if there's any way to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's always appreciated!

Comment: With a very small example 'require' + multi-page works. So I have to add more code until it is not working...

Comment: Added a small not working example (see above)

Comment: In Single, have you tried `<form action="index.php" method="post" data-ajax="false">`?

Comment: No, but that was the solution. Thanks!